Camel Route Template and Route Builder as separate Spring Boot App
I have a spring boot camel app (App1) with custom route template ("myTemplate"). This app will not run on its own. It will be included as a dependency in other apps.
I want to create another spring boot camel app (App2) involving templated camel routes referencing the template ("myTemplate") created in App1 .
When I run the App2, it is not able to find the template. It throws error "Cannot find RouteTemplate with id myTemplate"
I am not able to use the template in the other apps. Doesn't camel support this?
